# Highcharts working on jsfiddle but failing on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[error on site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR1UO.gif)

Good night,
Hope you can help me, I'm using highcharts to do some charts on my site and everything was going fine until the last chart, for some reason instead of writing the correct values as it shoul I'm getting [object Object], I've tried the same code on jsfidle and it's ok.

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    "xAxis":{"categories":[{"name":1,
    "categories":["a","b","c"]},{"name":2,"categories":["a","b","c"]},{"name":3,"categories":["a","b","c"]},{"name":4,"categories":["a","b","c"]},{"name":5,"categories":["a","b","c"]},{"name":6,"categories":["a","b","c"]},{"name":7,"categories":["a","b","c"]},{"name":8,"categories":["a","b","c"]},{"name":9,"categories":["a","b","c"]},{"name":10,"categories":["a","b","c"]}]},
    "series":[{"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,1,7,7,0,21,11,4,23,23,5,33,30,0],"name":"Forecast","color":"#124191","stack":"male"},{"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,1,7,7,0,21,11,4,21,22,5,21,22,0],"name":"Actual","color":"#00C9FF","stack":"female"}],
    "chart":{"type":"column",
    "renderTo":"container",
    "zoomType":"xy",
    "marginTop":"100",
    "marginBottom":"100",
    "columnColor":["#509be6","#124191","#90ed7d","#f7a35c","#8085e9","#f15c80","#e4d354","#8085e8","#8d4653","#91e8e1"]},
    "title":{"text":"Tests"},
    "yAxis":{"allowDecimals":false,"min":0,"title":{"text":"Total"}},"plotOptions":{"column":{"stacking":"normal"}},"legend":{"style":"text-align:center","width":"270"},"credits":{"enabled":false}});
});
```

I'm using the latest version of Highcharts and Jquery 1.8.2,

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories) categories accepts Array of string as parameters. You are passing array of objects hence it is displaying `[object object]`.
There is [plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) for group categories if you need.